# If a non-SSL-enabled domain is requested via https will Apache serve a different, SSL-enabled domain on the same server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect

I am hosting several websites on an Apache server (e.g. http://www.example.com), only one of which has an SSL certificate (e.g. https://www.example.net).  Is it possible to set up Apache so that an attempt to browse to https://www.example.com does not result in Apache serving https://www.example.net?  If so, how?

I ask this because my hosting provider states:

> ...if an SSL connection is attempted to any IP on the server and there is
>   no SSL virtualhost available for that domain, it connects to the first
>   available SSL virtualhost listed.
>   ...if there are multiple SSL virtualhosts on the machine, when there is no
>   match it will automatically connect to the first one shown in the
>   httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default you don't get a redirect at all, but as your hosting provider states: if no virtualhost is configured for a domain name, the first VirtualHost is the default that gets displayed. That is after you ignore the SSL warnings your web browser generates...

If you have only enabled SSL/TLS for `www.example.net` that is the site that will be displayed when connecting to `https://any-domain` or the `https://<ip-address of your server>`.

For that reason it is quite common to set up a blank website as the first VirtualHost before the VirtualHost stanza's of your valid domains.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/empty
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If it doesn't redirect by default what could I ask my hosting provider to undo so that it doesn't redirect?

Comment: @user20936 It does *not redirect*, Apache choses the first VirtualHost with HTTPS and *serves* that one.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, my memory misled me.  I'll have to change the question title.